# TPH inheritance not working as expected in Entity Framework Code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

I then inherit directly from it:

```
public class CustomerAddress : Address
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CompanyAddressBase : Address
{ }

public class MainOfficeAddress : CompanyAddressBase
{
    public int MainOfficeId { get; set; }
}

public class SubsidiaryAddress : CompanyAddressBase
{
    public int SubsidiaryId { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping is as follows:

```
public class CustomerAddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CustomerAddress>
{
    public CustomerAddressMap() 
    {
        this.ToTable("CustomerAddresses");
        //Properties here...
    }
}

public class CompanyAddressBaseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CompanyAddressBase>
{
    public CompanyAddressBaseMap() 
    {
        this.ToTable("CompanyAddresses");

        this.Map<MainOfficeAddress>(m => m.Requires("type")
            .HasValue((int)CompanyType.MainOffice)
            .IsRequired());

        this.Map<SubsidiaryAddress>(m => m.Requires("type")
            .HasValue((int)CompanyType.Subsidiary)
            .IsRequired());
    }
}

public class MainOfficeAddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MainOfficeAddress>
{
    public MainOfficeAddressMap ()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.MainOfficeId).HasColumnName("companyId")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class SubsidiaryAddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SubsidiaryAddress>
{
    public SubsidiaryAddressMap ()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.SubsidiaryId).HasColumnName("companyId")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And the registration of the `DbSets`:

```
public DbSet<CompanyAddressBase> CompanyAddresses { get; set; }
public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyAddressBaseMap());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MainOfficeAddressMap());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubsidiaryAddressMap());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerAddressMap());
```

However, when I try to save a company address (ie. main office or subsidiary), an exception is thrown:

> dbo.Addresses not found

Is the above not the correct configuration for TPH? Am I missing something?

Comment: In TPH you have to write whole hierarchy to single table, that corresponds your base entity for hierarchy. You are currently writing them to different tables which makes it unable to access them from single table.